# Is it possible to automate the addition of a video at the begining of a bunch of videos?

Tags: video, scripting, ffmpeg, automation, adobe-premiere

Is it possible to automatically add a video at the beginning of a bunch of videos.

For example I have a video of 1 min of pure branding and I want to be able to add that introductory video to a bunch of other videos and then export each one of those videos with introduction included.

Currently, I'm doing it manually on Adobe Premiere.

I am open to every kind of software with scripting capability (adobe premiere (if scripting is possible), ffmpeg) and just need to be able to set specific export settings (fps, resolution and codec for example).

Comment: What are the input formats? What is your required output format?

Comment: flv or mkv are ok for both input and output

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy if you are willing to use Matröska as a container. `mkvmerge` allows to merge multiple files without reencoding (which will be much better for you in all likelyhood).

```
mkvmerge -o output.mkv into.ogv + mainfile.ogv
```

You can also adjust the settings of the output file ("fps, resolution"), but codec will stay the same.